# Assign parameterised BigQuery magic to variable in Jupyter

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter

How can I assign the output of a BigQuery cell magic operation in Jupyter if it has parameters?

```
%%bq execute --query sql_my_query --to-dataframe
parameters:
- name: min_val
  type: STRING
  value: $min_val
- name: max_val
  type: STRING
  value: $max_val
```

I've tried placing a variable in front of the BQ magic (e.g. `myvar = %%bq ...`), I've tried using `myvar << %%bq`, adding parentheses or braces around the entire expression but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

There are no examples in the [examples](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/BigQuery%20Parameterization.ipynb) either except with the Python API, which seems a bit messy for something that should be fairly standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the query in one cell using the magic command.
But then to **execute** the query and supply the parameter values, do it in another cell **without** the magic command:

```
# in the first cell
%%bq query --name day_extract_query
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM @input_date) AS day
```

After that, execute using pure python with no magic

```
# then, in a second cell
query_params1 = [{ "name": "input_date",
                   "parameterType": { "type": "DATE" },
                   "parameterValue": { "value": "2019-01-03" } }]
day1 = day_extract_query.execute(query_params=query_params1).result()
```